# Inferring type of object from value of property in Typescript

Tags: typescript, casting

I have the following code in Typescript (simplified)

```
interface TimeoutOption {
  category: 'timeout'
  time: number
}

interface UserOption {
  category: Parameters<typeof addEventListener>[0]
}

type MyDelayOptions = Array<TimeoutOption | UserOption>


function delay(options: MyDelayOptions) {
  for (const option of options) {
    if (option.category === 'timeout') {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        // not relevant
      }, option.time) // need to cast and do (option as TimeoutOption) to not get an error
    }
  }
}
```

In order to avoid a compilation error I have to add the type assertion mentioned in the comment. For a human though it is clear that if the `category` is `'timeout'` my `option` is of type `TimeoutOption`. How can I make this work without the type assertion? Complete refactors welcome.

Comment: I get `Property 'time' does not exist on type 'UserOption'.`

Comment: @v-moe that's impossible, you are using a type guard, so the property `time` exists for sure and TypeScript knows it

Comment: Probably `DelayOptions` is shadowed from the type defined in the DOM (this is not how TypeScript resolves conflicts, but maybe I'm missing something). Why don't you try renaming it?

Comment: Must have missed an important part while simplifying, let me edit, please

Comment: Sorry, just edited, looks like `'something'` could not reproduce what I had with my actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `UserOption` defines `category` as type `string` (indirectly, but that's what it comes out as). As a result, `if (option.category === 'timeout')` doesn't discriminate between your two union members, because `UserOption` could easily have `category: "timeout"` just like `TimeoutOption` does. The discriminant (`category`) has to clearly discriminate the union, but it doesn't in your case.

You could test for the presence of `time` instead (see `***` below):

```typescript
function delay(options: MyDelayOptions) {
  for (const option of options) {
    if ("time" in option) { // ***
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        // not relevant
      }, option.time) // need to cast and do (option as TimeoutOption) to not get an error
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCrALYQPYFcwDyADmMNiMgN4BQyyCckA5tlAJ4BcyA5KVnmG61kfCFxC4MAI2jUAvtWqhIsRCgCqAZ2jFS5KsIbNWnZAAU4UOFhWaAPGDZEcMZHAAm7gKIA3COAAZYE1IEGgAPgBtAAYAXXlFR2dkAFk2ABEIABs4Nl0yEE1kAF5kAEEoKzY7dH58fP0AH2QtHRIC8MVqGFwQBD0Kd2zcgApsdvJNLjTMnLyJwoBKAzoYVmQRhEmwZHGB3dc9gs1lmjo6YFcRgCJRa+RQXYXT4XP6bZFMHHwS5G0wWrfMAjEbLYrhFZvc4AemhyBA2B2UGyEB8cHAr3OcgANE8BgA6UTLWHwiAQdwibD0OAhNwgCnuKljBZuIqAgQNEDLMBUhE7JgQHbo5DQKCsTEKOgKORAA)

Comment: Oh yes ... Just found out myself. Thought `Parameters<typeof addEventListener>[0]` would be a bit more narrowed down to `'click' | 'keydown' // etc.`

Comment: @v-moe - Ah, that makes sense. :-) They can't do that because it's possible to define your own event names, so the first argument has to be any string.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need a typeguard function here to confirm that `option` is of type `TimeoutOption`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Something like this should do it.

```
function isTimeout(option: TimeoutOption | UserOption): option is TimeoutOption {
  return (option as TimeoutOption).time !== undefined;
}

...

if (itTimeout(option) {
 // do stuff
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCrALYQPYFcwDyADmMNiMgN4BQyyCckA5tlAJ4BcyA5KVnmG61kfCFxC4MAI2jUAvtWqhIsRCgCqAZ2jFS5KsIbNWnZAAU4UOFhWaAPGDZEcMZHAAm7gKIA3COAAZYE1IEGgAPgBtAAYAXXlFR2dkAFk2ABEIABs4Nl0yEE1kAF5kAEEoKzY7dH58fP0AH2QtHRIC8MUYXBAEPQpg2px8AApsdvIuIYEGimbWqFmASi5x-uRgtExhwgmKGjooCDBcKAoxvbci6fq9pYA6UWQAQmLSnvcIGFAIdwBuBJdHp9ArIT45NgXfqaLhpTIQ2aaJYGOgwVjIEYIcghZBrUHYVx47HIg50DauEaDbYCKEFJYk4Rk%20jYsAian4ErIbRgG5gEYjZHFcIoplkgD0YuQIGwrKOWQgPjg4EZZLkABpcXtHttkRKpRBfiJsPQ4Dile4wcbafpTVs6rt%20siwMbpaymMc3BRoFBWCqFHQFHIgA)

Comment: There's no need for a type predicate in the code in the quesiton, which as was pointed out in the comments, doesn't have the problem the OP reported -- there's *already* a type guard in place (an `if`).

Comment: It's a good point, I was confused with typescripts ability to discriminate inner properties which is in fact not an issue here.

Comment: Now that the orginal question has been updated I believe this is now a valid solution along with the one posted by yourself @T.J.Crowder

Comment: It's your call. :-) I think bringing type predicates into it just confuses the basic issue, which is that the OP was trying to use `category` to discriminate between union members, but `category` couldn't do that. Also, they don't **need** a type predicate as you say in your opening sentence (though they may want one); again, an `if` is sufficient, it just needs to test the right thing. But I think the chief thing to do was to explain why their code wasn't working. (Which wasn't possible when you posted your answer, since the code at that time *was* working.)